# Regresar Arreglo de Caracteres Cómo Parametro o Valor en una Función de C++

Tags: c++

Tengo una rutina que pasa de tipo de dato `string` a `unsigned char[]` que es el siguiente:

```
unsigned char in[20];
string str = "BABABABAAB";

for(int aux = 0, tam_str = str.length(); aux != tam_str; aux += 2)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << str.substr(aux, 2);

    int valor;
    ss >> valor;

    in[aux/2] = valor;
}
```

Y quiero hacer de esta rutina una función que pueda recibir como parametros un arreglo de caracteres vacío y lo regrese "lleno", ¿cómo se podría hacer eso? ¿hay alguna forma mas optimizada de hacer eso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Quiero hacer de esta rutina una función que pueda recibir como parámetros un arreglo de caracteres vacío y lo regrese "lleno"

Depende de si quieres que el arreglo sea de tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación o de tamaño variable.

#### Tamaño conocido.

Para rellenar un arreglo de tamaño predefinido, debes pasarlo como referencia:

```
void convertir(const std::string &str, unsigned char (&in)[20])
{
    for (int aux = 0, tam_str = str.length(); aux != tam_str; aux += 2)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << std::hex << str.substr(aux, 2);

        int valor;
        ss >> valor;

        in[aux / 2] = valor;
    }
}
```

El código anterior sólo acepta formaciones de tamaño 20, si necesitas diferentes tamaños y éstos son conocidos en tiempo de compilación, puedes usar una plantilla:

```
template <std::size_t TAMANYO>
void convertir(const std::string &str, unsigned char (&in)[TAMANYO])
{
    for (int aux = 0, tam_str = str.length(); aux != tam_str; aux += 2)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << std::hex << str.substr(aux, 2);

        int valor;
        ss >> valor;

        in[aux / 2] = valor;
    }
}
```

Ten en cuenta que estoy siguiendo tu código en las propuestas anteriores y no se está comprobando que el arreglo de destino tenga suficientes elementos como para contener todos los datos del `std::string` de origen.

#### Tamaño desconocido.

Si el tamaño resultante depende del tamaño del parámetro entrante, lo mejor será usar un contenedor en lugar de un puntero:

```
void convertir(const std::string &str, std::vector<unsigned char> &in)
{
    in.reserve(str.length() / 2)

    for (int aux = 0, tam_str = str.length(); aux != tam_str; aux += 2)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << std::hex << str.substr(aux, 2);

        int valor;
        ss >> valor;

        in.push_back(valor);
    }
}
```

Pero si insistes en usar punteros (no deberías) necesitarás pasar el puntero por referencia y reservar memoria de manera acorde:

```
void convertir(const std::string &str, unsigned char *&in)
{
    in = new unsigned char[str.length() / 2];

    for (int aux = 0, tam_str = str.length(); aux != tam_str; aux += 2)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << std::hex << str.substr(aux, 2);

        int valor;
        ss >> valor;

        in[aux / 2] = valor;
    }
}
```

El código anterior tiene serios problemas:

- Debes gestionar la memoria manualmente.
- El alojado de memoria se realiza dentro de la función, no se sabe nada de cómo o cuándo será desalojada la memoria.

Para evitar estos problemas usa un puntero inteligente:

```
void convertir(const std::string &str, std::unique_ptr<unsigned char> &in)
{
    in = std::make_unique<unsigned char[]>(str.length() / 2);

    for (int aux = 0, tam_str = str.length(); aux != tam_str; aux += 2)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << std::hex << str.substr(aux, 2);

        int valor;
        ss >> valor;

        in[aux / 2] = valor;
    }
}
```

Con el puntero inteligente te olvidas de los problemas de gestión de memoria.

#### A tener en cuenta.

- He pasado el parámetro `str` como referencia constante porque no va a ser modificado.
- Usar alias de tipos te puede ayudar a hacer que el código sea más claro:

  - Arreglo de 20 elementos:

    ```
    using a20 = unsigned char[20];

    void convertir(const std::string &str, a20 &in);
    ```
  - vector:

    ```
    using vuchar = std::vector<unsigned char>;

    void convertir(const std::string &str, vuchar &in);
    ```
  - puntero inteligente:

    ```
    using puchar = std::unique_ptr<unsigned char>;

    void convertir(const std::string &str, puchar &in);
    ```

Comment: Te quería consultar algo mas, casi siempre declaro variables de tamaño dinámico de este tipo `unsigned char valor[n]`, en ese caso ¿cuál me recomendarías tu de los ejemplos que me diste? y ¿cómo podría pasar ese valor como referencia, es decir, cómo mandar a llamar las funciones? Ocupé tu tercer ejemplo pero cuando quiero pasar la variable `valor` de este modo `funcion("ABCD", &valor)`, me manda el error: `initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue`

Comment: Saludos @NoeCano respecto a tu primera duda, si `n` es una constante el tamaño de `char valor[n]` no será dinámico mientras que si `n` es una variable `char valor[n]` no es código estándar y no deberías usarlo, consulta alguna de [estas preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+vla) para saber por qué.  Respecto a mi tercer ejemplo, sólo con `funcion("ABCD", &valor)` no puedo saber que pasa, te animo a que abras una pregunta nueva con esa duda.

Comment: Gracias Paula, el valor de `n` siempre es fijo en efecto, y es conocido por el compilador en tiempo de ejecución, al decir "dinámico" me refería a que no siempre es 20 (a veces es 40, 80, etc) y por eso me pareció que de todos tus ejemplos el mejor era el tercero pero cómo te comentaba, recibo un error cuando quiero pasar la dirección de la variable (en el segundo parámetro)

Answer (score 0):

lo primero que se me ocurre es que la función sea de la forma

```
void nombre_funcion(string str, unsigned char *in){
      // rutina
}
```

donde el segundo parámetro es un puntero al arreglo de caracteres.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que si pasas el puntero por copia, si es reasignado, fuera de la función no se reflejará el cambio.